# Perform segue on google maps infowindow

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I have a Google Maps inserted like this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:mapView_ atIndex:0];
```

I would like to perform a segue on a Google Maps InfoWindow tap event:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoView" sender:self];
}
```

On the storyboard I attached the destination view to the sender view controller but it fails with an error message:

```
Receiver (<Controller>) has no segue with identifier 'infoView'
```

My question is where should I attach the destination controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the segue (arrow between the VCs) in interface builder and make sure `infoView` is set as the identifier in tab with the slider icon in the inspector on the right.